# Transferring data over SPI using DMA issue STM32F0 LL Driver

Tags: arm, embedded, stm32, spi, dma

I'm currently working on a project to send data for an application from a STM32F030c8 chip to a raspberry pi, the issue is data doesn't seem to be sending when i've enabled spi to use DMA and attempting to transfer. This is the current work i have so far, the STM acts as a SLAVE device and attempts to transfer when IRQ handler is called for the DMA channels.

IRQ Handler

```
void DMA1_Channel4_5_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN DMA1_Channel4_5_IRQn 0 */
  /* USER CODE END DMA1_Channel4_5_IRQn 0 */
  LL_GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LL_GPIO_PIN_8;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = LL_GPIO_MODE_ALTERNATE;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = LL_GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
  GPIO_InitStruct.OutputType = LL_GPIO_OUTPUT_PUSHPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = LL_GPIO_PULL_UP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = LL_GPIO_AF_0;
  LL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);
  prexfer();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN DMA1_Channel4_5_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END DMA1_Channel4_5_IRQn 1 */
}
```

RX + TX Buffers

```
struct _jd_frame_t {
    uint8_t data[JD_SERIAL_PAYLOAD_SIZE + 4];
} __attribute__((__packed__, aligned(4)));
typedef struct _jd_frame_t jd_frame_t;

jd_frame_t tempSend, tempRecv;
```

Start of Program put dummy data in tempSend, setup SPI+DMA RX

```
/* USER CODE END 2 */
  tempSend.data[0] = 100;
  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  setupReceive(&tempRecv, sizeof(tempRecv));
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
    // setup transfer
  }
```

Rx setup method to begin receiving data

```
void setupReceive(const void *receive, uint32_t numbytes){
  /* Reset the threshold bit */
    CLEAR_BIT(SPI2->CR2, SPI_CR2_LDMATX | SPI_CR2_LDMARX);
  // Reception setup
    LL_DMA_ConfigAddresses(DMA1, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_4, (uint32_t) & (SPI2->DR), (uint32_t) receive,
                           LL_DMA_DIRECTION_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY);
    LL_DMA_SetDataLength(DMA1, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_4, numbytes);
    // Enable SPI
    LL_SPI_EnableDMAReq_RX(SPI2);
    LL_SPI_Enable(SPI2);
    LL_DMA_EnableChannel(DMA1, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_4);
}
```

SPI + DMA transfer methods

```
void prexfer(){
  xfer(&tempSend, &tempRecv, sizeof(tempSend));
}

void xfer(const void *send, const void *receive, uint32_t numbytes){
  /* Reset the threshold bit */
    CLEAR_BIT(SPI2->CR2, SPI_CR2_LDMATX | SPI_CR2_LDMARX);
  // Reception setup
    LL_DMA_ConfigAddresses(DMA1, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_4, (uint32_t) & (SPI2->DR), (uint32_t) receive,
                           LL_DMA_DIRECTION_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY);
    LL_DMA_SetDataLength(DMA1, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_4, numbytes);
  // Transfer setup
    LL_DMA_ConfigAddresses(DMA1, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_5, (uint32_t) send, (uint32_t) & (SPI2->DR),
                           LL_DMA_DIRECTION_MEMORY_TO_PERIPH);
    LL_DMA_SetDataLength(DMA1, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_5, numbytes);
  // Enable SPI
    LL_SPI_EnableDMAReq_RX(SPI2);
    LL_SPI_EnableDMAReq_TX(SPI2);
    LL_SPI_Enable(SPI2);
    LL_DMA_EnableChannel(DMA1, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_4);
    LL_DMA_EnableChannel(DMA1, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_5);
}
```

DMA + SPI SETUP

```
static void MX_SPI2_Init(void)
{

  LL_SPI_InitTypeDef SPI_InitStruct = {0};

  LL_GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* Peripheral clock enable */
  LL_APB1_GRP1_EnableClock(LL_APB1_GRP1_PERIPH_SPI2);
  LL_AHB1_GRP1_EnableClock(LL_AHB1_GRP1_PERIPH_GPIOB);
  LL_AHB1_GRP1_EnableClock(LL_AHB1_GRP1_PERIPH_GPIOC);
  /**SPI2 GPIO Configuration
  PB12   ------> SPI2_NSS
  PB13   ------> SPI2_SCK
  PB14   ------> SPI2_MISO
  PB15   ------> SPI2_MOSI
  */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LL_GPIO_PIN_12 | LL_GPIO_PIN_13 | LL_GPIO_PIN_14 | LL_GPIO_PIN_15;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = LL_GPIO_MODE_ALTERNATE;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = LL_GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
  GPIO_InitStruct.OutputType = LL_GPIO_OUTPUT_PUSHPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = LL_GPIO_PULL_NO;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = LL_GPIO_AF_0;
  LL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /* SPI2 DMA Init */

  /* SPI2_RX Init */
  LL_DMA_SetDataTransferDirection(DMA1, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_4, LL_DMA_DIRECTION_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY);
  LL_DMA_SetChannelPriorityLevel(DMA1, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_4, LL_DMA_PRIORITY_LOW);
  LL_DMA_SetMode(DMA1, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_4, LL_DMA_MODE_NORMAL);
  LL_DMA_SetPeriphIncMode(DMA1, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_4, LL_DMA_PERIPH_NOINCREMENT);
  LL_DMA_SetMemoryIncMode(DMA1, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_4, LL_DMA_MEMORY_INCREMENT);
  LL_DMA_SetPeriphSize(DMA1, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_4, LL_DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE);
  LL_DMA_SetMemorySize(DMA1, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_4, LL_DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE);

  /* SPI2_TX Init */
  LL_DMA_SetDataTransferDirection(DMA1, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_5, LL_DMA_DIRECTION_MEMORY_TO_PERIPH);
  LL_DMA_SetChannelPriorityLevel(DMA1, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_5, LL_DMA_PRIORITY_LOW);
  LL_DMA_SetMode(DMA1, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_5, LL_DMA_MODE_NORMAL);
  LL_DMA_SetPeriphIncMode(DMA1, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_5, LL_DMA_PERIPH_NOINCREMENT);
  LL_DMA_SetMemoryIncMode(DMA1, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_5, LL_DMA_MEMORY_INCREMENT);
  LL_DMA_SetPeriphSize(DMA1, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_5, LL_DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE);
  LL_DMA_SetMemorySize(DMA1, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_5, LL_DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI2_Init 1 */
  /* SPI2 parameter configuration*/
  SPI_InitStruct.TransferDirection = LL_SPI_FULL_DUPLEX;
  SPI_InitStruct.Mode = LL_SPI_MODE_SLAVE;
  SPI_InitStruct.DataWidth = LL_SPI_DATAWIDTH_4BIT;
  SPI_InitStruct.ClockPolarity = LL_SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  SPI_InitStruct.ClockPhase = LL_SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  SPI_InitStruct.NSS = LL_SPI_NSS_HARD_INPUT;
  SPI_InitStruct.BitOrder = LL_SPI_MSB_FIRST;
  SPI_InitStruct.CRCCalculation = LL_SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  SPI_InitStruct.CRCPoly = 7;
  LL_SPI_Init(SPI2, &SPI_InitStruct);
  LL_SPI_SetStandard(SPI2, LL_SPI_PROTOCOL_MOTOROLA);
  LL_SPI_DisableNSSPulseMgt(SPI2);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI2_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * Enable DMA controller clock
  */
static void MX_DMA_Init(void)
{

  /* Init with LL driver */
  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  LL_AHB1_GRP1_EnableClock(LL_AHB1_GRP1_PERIPH_DMA1);
  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA1_Channel4_5_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel4_5_IRQn, 1);
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel4_5_IRQn);

}
```

So how the code should work is that when i setup RX & it receives data from the RPi it should call DMA1 IRQ handler to transfer data but it never gets called, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is your interrupt NVIC registered ?

Comment: Thanks for replying, yep under MX_DMA_Init, i actually manage to figure out the reason behind it, so it was actually calling the irq handler but only once, the issue was i wasn't resetting the global interrupt flag when it was set in DMA register, so on call of my IRQ handler i need to reset the global interrupt on the RX Channel using LL_DMA_ClearFlag_GI4(DMA1);

Comment: You should have a look at this : http://www.efton.sk/STM32/gotcha/g16.html